# Is it possible to render a texture while it is being written to?

Tags: opengl

I have an app that renders to a texture in one thread and another thread reads the data from this texture. The context between the two threads are shared. Is it possible for a race-condition to occur where the reading thread will read partial data?

Comment: Yes, that's basically a perfect setup for a data race.

Comment: @DietrichEpp I read online that issues can occur when something is writing to a context from two different threads, but I can't find anything saying the affects of writing on one and only reading from the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the OpenGL 4.6 core spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf), section 5.3.1:

> The contents of an object T are considered to have been changed once a command such as described in section 5.3 has completed. Completion of a command 1 may be determined either by calling `Finish`, or by calling `FenceSync` and executing a `WaitSync` command on the associated sync object.

In general, a *data race* happens when:

1. Two or more threads are writing to the same location in memory, and
2. At least one of the threads is writing, and
3. There is no synchronization between the threads.

You can see that in OpenGL, you need to either wait for `Finish()` or `WaitSync()` to return to know that your operations are synchronized. There are additional rules, note section 5.3.3:

> **Rule 4** If the contents of an object T are changed in a context other than the current context, T must be attached or re-attached to at least one binding point in the current context, or at least one attachment point of a currently bound container object C, in order to guarantee that the new contents of T are visible in the current context.

So if you write to a texture in thread A, and read from it in thread B, you have to do the following:

1. Create a sync object.
2. Signal the sync object from thread A once the write is finished.
3. Wait for the sync object in thread B.
4. Rebind the texture in thread B.

After these steps have completed, you can read from the texture in thread B.

**Note:** You may find that code with a data race will "work correctly" if you test it on your own computer. This is not surprising... sometimes it will work, sometimes it won't. Maybe it will always work on your computer and blow up on someone else's computer. Better to get things right with thread synchronization, just testing is not good enough.

Answer (score 1):

Possible, yes absolutely.

It is never necessary though. There are fine synchronization primitves available in GLsync and glFinish and you have no reason not to use them.

Exactly what the effects are from the data race are unspecified. You may end up reading half a texture, you may invoke a fatal error in the driver, or maybe it will just stop.